# Define make variable from $(shell) as a string in C

Tags: c, makefile

I am compiling code using a makefile for an embedded application on the STM32f4 family of chips.

When I do:

Makefile:

```
DEFINES += -DGIT_HASH="test hash"
```

In my `main.c`:

```
const char * git_hash = GIT_HASH;
```

When I print out `git_hash`, I get `test hash`.

What I would like to do is:

Makefile:

```
COMMIT_HASH = $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)
DEFINES += -DGIT_HASH=$(COMMIT_HASH)
```

In my `main.c`:

```
const char * git_hash = GIT_HASH;
```

I get an error:

```
<command-line>:0:10: error: 'c1920a032c487a55b1b109d8774faf05e2ba42d0' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/run/main.c:173:25: note: in expansion of macro 'GIT_HASH'
 const char * git_hash = GIT_HASH;
```

I am wondering why the `COMMIT_HASH` is not treated the same way as a string. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: For a few characters of code, use backticks (`). For whole lines, a four-character space indentation. It makes the post more readable.

Comment: That first example shouldn't work either as written. The shell should remove the quotes when it passes the flag to the compiler/preprocessor. See the output from `gcc -DGIT_HASH="foo bar" -E - <<<'const char * git_hash = GIT_HASH;'` for example. Are you sure that's exactly what you are using? (Are you perhaps using `gcc '$(DEFINES)' ...` in your makefile recipe line?)

Comment: I do a step where: CFLAGS += $(DEFINES) @Charles Duffy thanks for the edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that `#define` causes the precompiler to do a straight character for character replacement. So in your first example,

```
const char * git_hash = GIT_HASH;
```

becomes

```
const char * git_hash = "test hash";
```

The compiler is fine with this since it sees a literal string.

However, in your second example, it becomes

```
const char * git_hash = c1920a032c487a55b1b109d8774faf05e2ba42d0;
```

Now when the compiler does it's job, it sees a variable name, NOT a string literal, as I think you intend. To fix this, you need to be sure that the hash is enclosed in quotes. One possible solution is to change the Makefile to `DEFINES += -DGIT_HASH=\"$(COMMIT_HASH)\"`.

Comment: And one solution is to change the Makefile to `DEFINES += -DGIT_HASH=\"$(COMMIT_HASH)\"`

Comment: @nos Thanks. I added that to my answer.